# WooCommerce load products from thrid party API

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am just starting with woocommerce. As per documentation we need to import products to our database which have to be listed in our website. Basically app which we are developing act as a application where the role of database is very minimal. Vendor app will provide API For login, logout, product listing and everything. All I need to do is to integrate those API in my woocommerce app. What is the best way to do it? Is there any woocommerce hook available to achieve this? Is there any way to fetch the products from API rather from database??

Comment: What is the role of WC in this use case? The API provide support for buying and adding to cart?

Comment: This is just too broad. It's either you will make this a little more simple question or you have to find a programmer who can help you work on it.

Comment: @JunaidAhmed It wont... API provides only product list... woocommerce will take care of buying and adding to cart

Comment: @Reigel Rather than showing products from DB...I need to fetch API

Comment: There's no function in WooCommerce that I know that would fetch the products from other source. You most likely need to create this function; or import the products to WooCommerce database.

Comment: Even with WordPress itself as a source but not as WooCommerce, it's not that easy. Though WooCommerce is just part of WordPress. WooCommerce is not ready for this, yet. My opinion.

Comment: Okay. I think I know what you're trying to do. I have been working on a project which gets art from Adobe Stock. The search was modified to get items from Adobe Stock API and just display them. If a user wanted to buy any art, they'll just click on it and a product is created for them on the fly using information for that API item and added to cart.

Comment: You can modify your listing pages i.e. archives, products page, single product page and pass around the product information from page to page and use your API endpoints to fetch the product information. Once someone tries to buy it, create a unique (if product has variations) or find that product in WC if it was already created by another user and just add it to cart. Make sense?

Comment: @agree with Junaid Ahmed
I have created one wordpress website in which product comes from API on fly and displaying on product page and single product page.once user click on add to cart, product insert into woo commerce-word press db and also add into cart same time. and from there all word press control like shipping / coupon / tax start to apply on it.
you can do it that way as well.

Comment: @JunaidAhmed thats what I want to do. It would be really helpful if you explain a bit in detail

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to Stack Overflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Try this solution : [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213214/integrate-product-feed-api-in-woocommerce](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213214/integrate-product-feed-api-in-woocommerce) I'm sure this will help you

Comment: Try this solution : [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213214/integrate-product-feed-api-in-woocommerce](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213214/integrate-product-feed-api-in-woocommerce) I'm sure this will help you

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is lots of ways to achieve your goal. The best and with minial efforts and high performance. You can fetch API's response in memory instead of database and then store it to Redis cache.

Redis cache exipre in a specified time interval then again call will be made to API and cache will update. You can schedule frequency of caching based on your latency.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Woocommerce has a REST API that works quite well. If I understood right you want to fetch the products from an external source and "show" them to your Woocommerce app, I think you must "import" them to the WP database first, you can't skip that step. I don't think you can connect Woocommerce to your vendors database directly.

So for importing your vendors products into your WC you can use the provided REST API. You can easily create a product in Woocommerce using Curl:

```
curl -X POST https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products \
    -u consumer_key:consumer_secret \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{
  "name": "Premium Quality",
  "type": "simple",
  "regular_price": "21.99",
  "description": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.",
  "short_description": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.",
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 9
    },
    {
      "id": 14
    }
  ],
  "images": [
    {
      "src": "http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_front.jpg",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "src": "http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_back.jpg",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}'
```

See full [API Docs](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/) for more information.

EDIT:

I've just remembered that there is a tool called [WP All Import](http://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/) that may help you a lot accomplishing this task. As far as I know you can schedule automatic imports from XML/CSV external sources. You can update all kind of WP objects such as WC Products. Might be worth it taking a look.